class member address change after std::function call
I'm trying to implement two classes like those shown in code below, class A is the mother class that is more general while class B is a specialized child class that declares on it's own the std::function inherited from the first class.
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

struct double_vec
{
  std::vector<double> p;
  std::vector<double> v;
};

typedef std::function<void ()> i_function;

class A
{
  public:
  A(){};
  A(std::vector<double_vec*> vec, i_function p_function, i_function v_function)
  {
    this->m_vectors = vec;
    this->m_function = p_function;
  };

  void apply()
  {
    std::cout << "address after function call: " << &m_vectors << std::endl;
    m_function();
  };

  protected:

  i_function m_function;
  std::vector<double_vec*> m_vectors;
};

class B: public A
{
  public:
  B(std::vector<double_vec*> vec)
  {
    this->m_vectors = vec;

    load_functions();
  };

  private:
  void load_functions()
  {
    m_function = [&]()
    {
      std::cout << "address after function call: " << &m_vectors << std::endl;
    };
  };
};

int main()
{

  std::vector<std::vector<double_vec>> vectors;

  std::vector<B> b;

  for(int i=0; i<1; ++i)
  {
    std::vector<double_vec> temp;
    std::vector<double_vec*> reference_vector;

    temp.resize(10);
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    { 
      temp.at(i).p.resize(10,1);
      temp.at(i).v.resize(10,3);
    }

    vectors.push_back(temp);
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
      reference_vector.push_back(&vectors.back().at(i));

    B temp_b(reference_vector);
    b.push_back(temp_b);
  }

  b.front().apply();
}

and this is my output:
address before function call: 0x55a934dc2320 
address after function call: 0x7ffc284c1130

When i tried to access the vector from the function declared in the child class using lambdas, i noticed that the data stored wasn't right and, upon further analysis, the address of the class member changed after function call.
As the address of m_vectors changed, it doesn't points to significant data anymore and the data accessed was undefined.
When trying to reproduce the problem on a code with the bare minimum i noticed that unless i created a vector of the data to be stored (the variable vectors in the main function) and/or a vector of said class (b in the main function) the problem didn't appear.
Just like what happens when using a single std::vector<double_vec> and a single variable of class B i expected that the address of the class member m_vectors wouldn't change.
I need the address not to change to be able to access the stored information
I tried using [this]() and [&,this]() for the lambda but neither changed the result
Declaring the function with virtual methods instead of std::function makes things work, but there's a child class declared in a similar manner as B where i need to use the std::function instead so it's not a good solution.
I'm unsure where the problem even lies so i'd be glad if someone could explain to me what happened.

Neither of your cout statements prints before, they both print after

Old deleted question: Memory address of a std::vector member changes after std::function call defined in mother class


m_function = [&]() You're capturing this.   2. temp_b is not the same object as b.front(). Then what is this inside the lambda?


The address of an object cannot change, an object is somewhere, the address characterize the object. So here we are seeing different objects.
The 1st created B is temp_b, then it is copied in the vector b. After elements are added in vector b and vector can rearrange replacing its first element by an another copy.
The last displayed address is the address of Bs member at begin of vector b, it can't be the address of the initial temp_bs member.

One problem I see is this line:
reference_vector.push_back(&vectors.back().at(i));

You are storing raw pointers to double_vec objects that are inside the elements of vectors.
This can lead to dangling pointers in reference_vector, and thus also in the B objects in b.
As you keep pushing more objects into vectors, eventually its size will try to exceed its capacity and it will have to reallocate its internal array to grow its capacity. This will copy/move the existing double_vec objects inside of vectors to new memory addresses, thus invalidating the pointers you had already pushed into reference_vector and copied into b.
To avoid this, you will need to  use either vectors.reserve() or vectors.resize() before entering the outer loop.

I tried implementing multiple loops to make sure all vectors were all declared before being pushed and also tried using the reserve asking for a capacity bigger than what i needed but the address keeps changing after i passed them. I also want to precise that the address seems to change between before m_function call and after it's call

The problem was that the lambda is declared at initialization and thus capture the address of temp_b.
When everything is then copied in the vector the address of the std::function stays temp_b that is now dereferenced.
calling load_functions() after temp_b is copied onto the vector b gave this output
address before function call: 0x559c38bfa7a8
address after function call: 0x559c38bfa7a8

confirming it was a problem of when the lambda captures the address.
